# Need to change date alone in filename

Tags: linux

i want to list files based on date and change the date alone in the files in a directory

files now:

abc051217.log

xyz051217.log

ccc051217.log

ddd051217.log

In the above i want to select only files need to rename the date only for those files like below

file after:

abc021217.log

xyz021217.log

ccc021217.log

ddd021217.log

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mmv`. `mmv` uses standard shell patterns with '?' matching a single character and '*' matching 0 or more characters, which are referenced in the target pattern with '#' + number (starting from 1).

So in your use case

```
mmv -n '*??????.log' '#102#4#5#6#7.log'
```

The option `-n` is dry-run, so `mmv` does not actually remove your files, but just prints out what it would do. After verifying it really does what you want, run the command again without `-n`.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the files which you want to rename in test.txt
test.txt

```
abc051217.log
xyz051217.log
ccc051217.log
ddd051217.log
```

---

Use below code to rename as per requirement .

Code .

---

```
i=021217;sed '/^$/d' test.txt|awk -v i="$i"  '{print "mv" " " $1 " " substr($1,1,3)i".log"}'  | sh
```

---

Output

```
abc021217.log
xyz021217.log
ccc021217.log
ddd021217.log
```